# Inner deck guardrail posts and deck framing connectors

Tags: code-compliance, deck

I am mounting the deck guard rail posts inside the frame before adding the decking.  I have used deck framing connection hardware as suggested in the Simpson Strong-Tie [deck connection guide](https://embed.widencdn.net/pdf/plus/ssttoolbox/q4qw4c2zsj/F-DECKCODE17.pdf).

One thing not clear to me is what to do when the post and connection hardware (e.g., joist hanger or angle bracket) interfere with each other? Do you space out the post to clear the hardware or do you remove the hardware so you get a flush fit, relying on the carriage bolts, blocking and tension ties to keep the frame together. This detail seems to be missing from all the online tutorials, diagrams etc.

### Example: Simpson Strong-tie Inner Guardrails via Timber Screws with Blocking

For example, in the aforementioned, they showed one method for internally attaching guardrail posts using timber screws (instead of carriage bolts) and blocking, but they don't show any connection hardware such as joist hangers or a framing angle in the corner. The figure indicates that connecting hardware isn't shown, but they don't indicate either whether all other hardware is required, and how you get a flush fit with the post if the hardware is in place.

[image: Internal Guard Posts with Timber Screws]

### Example: Lowe's Inner Guardrails with Carriage Bolts and Blocking

Lowe's also has some [detailed instructions](https://www.lowes.com/n/how-to/build-a-deck-composite-decking-and-railings) using more traditional carriage bolts, but with blocking and tension ties (likely reflecting [newer building methods coming out of the Virginia Tech study](https://www.deckmagazine.com/design-construction/railings/code-compliant-guardrail-posts_o)).

Their corner blocking layout does not appear to include an framing angle bracket in the corner due to how flush the post is (below).  Does this imply the carriage bolts and blocking is enough to ensure structural integrity of the joist framing?
[image: Lowe's internal guardrail posts on a corner]

In Lowe's example of inner guardrail mounted on a rim joist, we can see at least half of a joist visible.  Is it a half of a joist hanger?  The toe-nailing slots on the joist hanger would have pushed out the post from the joist, but as you can see the inner guardrail post looks like it is laying fairly flush against the 2x8 joist.  Is that just an optical illusion and the post is offset from the joist?

[image: Lowe's example inner guardrail post on a rim joist]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Does this imply the carriage bolts and blocking is enough to ensure structural integrity of the joist framing?"

From what you show in the illustrations, yes.
The installation of the carriage bolts & blocking ensure the structural integrity, and, if you install them carefully, replace the function of the framing angle bracket.